Listen to all events a class raises, without using WithEvents
I'm trying to use the connection point interfaces (IConnectionPoint/IConnectionPointContainer) to listen to all events created by an object. I'm doing this dynamically for unit testing - so I give a workbook object to my class and get a log of all the click, selection_change, worksheet_added events with timestamps, without explicitly defining the event listeners it's all automatic.

Background
My understanding is when an event source interface is defined in VBA 2 things are made

Early bound interface with vtable layout for the event handler methods: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130611-00/?p=4113
Late bound dispatch interface with dispids for the event handler methods: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130612-00/?p=4103

Normally in COM if you have the type library upfront, you make your event sink object (listener) implement the Early Bound event interface IFooEvents, then call
IConnectionPointContainer.Find(IID_FooEvents).Advise(eventSink_IFooEvents)

However if you want to do this late-bound then you can instead make your event listener have IDispatch interface with DispIDs that match the FooEvents interface, if both are dual or dispatch interfaces. Like how we use dispid -4 for default member, dispid 15 may be the expected address for the callback function for the Worksheet_Change event.
Since the methods are called by dispid through IDispatch::Invoke, I was hoping you could override that method with a custom one to log the method calls but not actually invoke anything. What I did was this - a class with IDispatchInvoke overloaded (using vtable patching):
Class OmniEventListener Implements IDispatch
    Private Sub IDispatch_Invoke(ByVal dispIDMember As Long, ByVal riid As LongPtr, ByVal lcid As Long, ByVal wFlags As Integer, ByVal pDispParams As LongPtr, ByVal pVarResult As LongPtr, ByVal pExcepInfo As LongPtr, ByVal puArgErr As LongPtr)
        'Custom IDispatch::Invoke returns HResult S_OK for everything and logs any calls
        ' so it can be used as the event sink everywhere    
        MsgBox printf("IDispatchVB_InvokeVB dispid={}", dispIDMember)
        Err.ReturnHResult = 0
    End Sub
End Class

So that class basically says "whatever dispid was, just log the call and move on", meaning this is a universal event sink,
Then to wire up on a random COM object we have:
Private Function GetConnection(ByVal src As Object, Optional ByVal listener As Object, Optional ByRef outCN As IConnectionPoint) As Long

    Dim container As IConnectionPointContainer = src 'will throw if src exposes no event container   
    
    Dim enum As IEnumConnectionPoints = container.EnumConnectionPoints()

    Do While enum.Next(1, outCN) = 0
        Dim iid As UUID
        outCN.GetConnectionInterface iid
       
        MsgBox printf("Connection point {}", UUIDToString(iid)) 'IID_FooEvents
        If Not listener Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "Advising"
            On Error Resume Next 'try advise using IDispatch won't always work but will sometimes
            Dim cookie As Long = outCN.Advise(listener)
            On Error GoTo 0
            Debug.Print "Advised " ; cookie
            If cookie <> 0 Then Return cookie
        End If
    Loop
    'No IDispatch compatible connection found
    Set outCN = Nothing
    Return 0
End Function


Sub TestUsingExcelAppEvents()
    Dim xl As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Debug.Print "Got", xl.name
    Dim cn As IConnectionPoint
    Dim cookie As Long = GetConnection(xl, New OmniEventListener, outCN:=cn)
    If cookie <> 0 Then
        'This raises the NewWorkbook event, which pops a message box 
        ' from our OmniEventListener::IDispatch::Invoke with dispid 0x61d - see screenshot
        xl.workbooks.add 
        cn.Unadvise cookie
    End If
    xl.quit
End Sub

Got the connection point corresponding to AppEvents in the IDL:

And the correct event dispid when RaiseEvent Application_NewWorkbook happens:

What I have so far
Hopefully that all makes sense. And my method works for MSForms controls like Matt got working in MVVM example with ConnectToConnectionPoint api here - src code on wine shows it's just using the interfaces under the hood.
However my method does not allow me to connect to VBA event objects that raise events, e.g.
Class SimpleEventSource
    Public Event AfterAdd()
    
    Public Sub DoAdd()
        RaiseEvent AfterAdd
    End Sub
End Class

If I do cookie = GetConnection(mSimpleEventSource, New OmniEventListener, outCN) then it does not connect. So there are no connection points that I can successfully Advise by passing my OmniEventListener. And therefore I cannot log Event AfterAdd
But I know that all VBA classes including the SimpleEvents one are dual and I know the AfterAdd event corresponds to dispid of 1 for the source interface. You can see it if you compile using VB6 or twinBASIC and look at the IDL. So how can I hook into the events of any vba class?
I'm making my logging library to help unit test events being raised by logging when that happened. I'm building this in twinBASIC and the target is to unit test VBA code.

Appendix IDL (OLEWoo)
I looked at the typelibs in OLEWoo to get the IDL (Interface Definition Language) that describes the various interfaces. Here is what I saw
Excel object model (see this uuid matches the one in the message box in the screenshot above):

twinBASIC/VBA:

twinBASIC/VBA:

Excel (see the id 0x0000061d on the NewWorkbook method of the interface matches the dispid in the messagebox in the screenshot earlier, showing it is invoked on the omni event sink in response to the event happening):


We can't see how mSimpleEventSource was created.  But if it is late-bound then surely with CreateObject(), so not with WithEvents.  Look here

mSimpleEventSource is supplied by the user late bound to my library. And then I want to connect a logger to it to log all the events out creates. It's just an instance of New SimpleEventSource but it could be anything that implemented IConnectionPointContainer unless I'm mistaken

Not a full answer but some progress:
Whilst it's true that all VBA interfaces are dual, it is not true that because of this the connection points will allow you to use a late binding vtable (i.e. expose the correct dispids, rather than the correct vtable layout).
It is up to the event source to decide what type of event sinks it allows; either As Object explicitly like MSForms Controls, As Object implicitly like Excel Document Object events, or the specific early bound event interface like vba classes through a vtable.
It may be possible to create an object with a vtable and stub methods that are flexible to any arguments, or a class which takes a description of the interface and inserts stub methods appropriately, or event takes an ITypeInfo of the event sync interface and does some reflection to generate a vtable accordingly. ITypeInfo of VBA classes is hard to come by though.

Can you write little more about how we can do it in vba without losing Mac compatibility?

@MDIsmailHosen what object are you trying to listen to the events of?

Textbox and Combobox of userform.
